# Segmentation error while inserting into binary tree

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I cannot figure  out how to run this correctly, gives segmentation error. A piece of code is below. Can you look at head too , i am not sure if it is right way of initialising head to null in another file , it is run as follows :

```
Table tb ;
tb= initialise_table (table_size); 
tb = insert(text_words,tb);

//these 3 typedef declarations are in a "some.h" file       
typedef struct node * tree_ptr; 
typedef char* Key_Type; 
typedef struct table* Table;  
struct node { 
    Key_Type element; 
    tree_ptr left; 
    tree_ptr right; 
}; 

struct table { 
    tree_ptr head; 
};

Table init_table()  {

   Table head = NULL;

} 
Table insert(Key_Type key ,Table  temp )  {
    tree_ptr t = (tree_ptr)malloc(sizeof(tree_ptr));
    t->element = key;
    // t->left = t->right = NULL;
    if (temp->head==NULL) {
        temp = (Table)malloc (sizeof (Table)); 
        temp->head = t;
        printf("empty tree ");
    }    
    else {          
        temp = insert(t->element,temp);
        printf("inserted into "); 
    }

    return temp;   
    printf("wowo!");
}
```

Comment: To start with, [don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Then run your program in a debugger to see *where* the crash happens. If it's not in your code, then walk up the function call stack until you arrive at your code.

Comment: But my guess is that it's because the `malloc` call allocates the size of a *pointer* and not the whole structure. Don't use type-aliases for pointers, it's easy to introduce errors like this then.

Comment: Hi , i just deleted that casting , but no luck still

Comment: @RaminTaghizada Change `tree_ptr  t = (tree_ptr)malloc(sizeof(tree_ptr));` to `tree_ptr  t = malloc(sizeof(*t));`. This should solve your error.

Comment: but when i allocate a memory for temp in the beginning of the code it gives result , but i m sure does not insert into tree

Comment: Change `temp = malloc (sizeof (*temp));` too. And notice the pattern.

Comment: See [Is it a good idea to `typedef` pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers)

Answer (score 1):

The primary issue is in the code which, you say, is used to invoke the functions:

```
Table tb;

tb = insert(text_words, tb);
```

You have an uninitialized pointer, `tb`, which you pass to the function. Inside the function, you have:

```
Table insert(Key_Type key, Table temp)
{
    tree_ptr t = (tree_ptr)malloc(sizeof(*t));  // Fixed size
    t->element = key;
    // t->left = t->right = NULL;
    if (temp->head==NULL)
    {
```

You're therefore accessing (dereferencing) the undefined pointer, and your program is crashing.

You should, I assume, be initializing your table with `table_init()`, but that function is actually no help whatsoever.  It defines and initializes a local variable, but doesn't return anything even though it promises to do so.

Please see [Is it a good idea to `typedef` pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers)  The short answer is 'No, it usually isn't a good idea'.

You still have problems even if you fix the calling code like this (a necessary but not sufficient step):

```
Table tb = NULL;
tb = insert(text_words, tb);
```

or maybe:

```
Table tb = init_table();
tb = insert(text_words, tb);
```

but you need a seriously upgraded version of `init_table()`, such as:

```
Table init_table(void)
{
   Table root = malloc(sizeof(*head));
   root->head = NULL;
   return root;
}
```

Your code in `insert()` needs to ensure that it does not dereference a null pointer (instead of an indeterminate pointer).

```
Table insert(Key_Type key, Table root)
{
    tree_ptr t = (tree_ptr)malloc(sizeof(*t));  // Fixed size
    t->element = key;
    t->left = t->right = NULL;
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        root = init_table();
        root->head = t;
    }
    else
    {
        …
    }
    return root;
}
```

Given the `Key_Type` is a `char *` in disguise, you may need to review how you save the keys in the tree structure; you may need to use `strdup()` to copy the data.  It is impossible to say for sure without seeing how you are managing the strings that you pass to the `insert()` function.  It could be OK to just save the pointer if the calling code ensures that a new pointer is passed each time.  OTOH, if the same pointer is passed each time, you definitely need to copy the data, and using `strdup()` is a sensible way of doing that.  Note that `strdup()` is standard on POSIX; it is not part of standard C.

Comment: Hi , cannot compare each key element with tree node , give same elements again each time , i do not understand strdup function , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's one major problem:

```
tree_ptr t = (tree_ptr) malloc(sizeof(tree_ptr));
```

should be:

```
tree_ptr t = (tree_ptr) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Your code doesn't actually do any binary search.  Indeed, it just infinitely recurses creating new nodes.  Try something more like this:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Node
{ 
  char        *element; 
  struct Node *left; 
  struct Node *right; 

} Node;

typedef struct
{
  Node  *root;
  size_t size;

} Tree;

void  Tree_init(Tree *t);
Node *Tree_insert(Tree *t, const char *key);
void  Tree_insert_r(Node *subtree, Node *n, size_t size);
void  Tree_pre_order_r(Node *subtree);

void Tree_init(Tree *t)
{
  t->root = NULL;
  t->size = 0;
}    

Node *Tree_insert(Tree *t, const char *key)
{
  Node *ret = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));

  if (ret)
  {
    ret->left = ret->right = NULL;

    if ((ret->element = strdup(key)))  /* make a copy of key */
    {
      if (NULL != t->root)
        Tree_insert_r(t->root, ret, t->size);
      else
        t->root = ret;

      ++t->size;
    }
    else
    {
      free(ret);
      ret = NULL;
    }
  }

  return ret;
}

void Tree_insert_r(Node *subtree, Node *n, size_t size)
{
  int cmp = strcmp(n->element, subtree->element);

  if (cmp < 0 || (cmp == 0 && size % 2 == 0))
  {
    if (NULL != subtree->left)
      subtree = subtree->left;
    else
    {
      subtree->left = n;
      return;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    if (NULL != subtree->right)
      subtree = subtree->right;
    else
    {
      subtree->right = n;
      return;
    }    
  }

  Tree_insert_r(subtree, n, size);
}

void Tree_pre_order_r(Node *subtree)
{
  if (NULL == subtree)
    return;

  fprintf(stdout, "'%s'\n", subtree->element);

  Tree_pre_order_r(subtree->left);
  Tree_pre_order_r(subtree->right);
}

int main()
{
  Tree t;

  Tree_init(&t);
  Tree_insert(&t, "Hello");
  Tree_insert(&t, "World!");
  Tree_insert(&t, "etc.");

  Tree_pre_order(t.root);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help , again same problem segmentation error , i run it with valgrind but cannot find out where the error is

Comment: It might help if you post a more complete version of your code.  The above fragment doesn't tell us enough and doesn't allow us to test it.

Comment: hi ,i just edited into above code , other files are perfectly fine .

Comment: If I answered your question, then you could accept my answer.